# HTML Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV)

Tags: html, csv, file-upload, input, content-type

I have a file upload object on my page:

```
<input type="file" ID="fileSelect" />
```

with the following excel files on my desktop:

> 1. file1.xlsx
> 2. file1.xls
> 3. file.csv

I want the file upload to ***ONLY*** show `.xlsx`, `.xls`, & `.csv` files.

Using the `accept` attribute, I found these content-types took care of `.xlsx` & `.xls` extensions...

> `accept`= application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet (.XLSX)
>
> `accept`= application/vnd.ms-excel (.XLS)

However, I cannot find the correct content-type for an Excel CSV file! Any suggestions?

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/LzLcZ/

Comment: most browsers do not respect the accept attribute since it can be used to encurage users who are not paying attention to transmit sensitive files.

Comment: @tletnes not true, it's supported by most major browsers

Comment: You can also try this  

if ($.trim($('#OriginalFileName').val()) != "") 
{
   var ext =    $('#OriginalFileName').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if ($.inArray(ext, ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xlsx', 'xls']) == -1) 
{
   $('#OriginalFileNameValid').html('Use .doc,.docx,.pdf files');
                }
            }

Comment: In case any other Ubuntu users are getting confused by this, I have found that in Ubuntu, Firefox defaults to showing "All Files", but adds whatever your "accept" attribute is to the filetype dropdown in the file selection dialog.

Answer (score 1896):

Well this is embarrassing... I found the solution I was looking for and it couldn't be simpler. I used the following code to get the desired result.

```html
<label for="fileSelect">Spreadsheet</label>
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

### Valid Accept Types:

For **CSV** files (.csv), use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

For **Excel Files 97-2003** (.xls), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

For **Excel Files 2007+** (.xlsx), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

For **Text Files** (.txt) use:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/plain" />
```

For **Image Files** (.png/.jpg/etc), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

For **HTML Files** (.htm,.html), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/html" />
```

For **Video Files** (.avi, .mpg, .mpeg, .mp4), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
```

For **Audio Files** (.mp3, .wav, etc), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" />
```

For **PDF Files**, use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf" />
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/LzLcZ/144/

---

*NOTE:*

If you are trying to display Excel CSV files (`.csv`), do ***NOT*** use:

- `text/csv`
- `application/csv`
- `text/comma-separated-values` (*works in Opera only*).

---

If you are trying to display a *particular file type* (for example, a `WAV` or `PDF`), then this will almost always work...

```
 <input type="file" accept=".FILETYPE" />
```

Here's the reason  why it is so:

The `application`  types often mean where to open the file.
For example, Abode Reader.
But when this file is  uploaded, the browser doesn't care about opening and asking that app about it. But the extension, however, or type words like the MIME `image`  or `audio` etcetera work applying  directly to file units.

It is possible to use them in relation to a `File`  DOM instance.
So, you should use the extension format name.
On many devices, like mobiles, it is seen when you click select File, that the non- accepted files in the user menu are excluded in grey...
Have a great time spent with your files!

Comment: It seems that Chrome supports this attribute, but Firefox is still working on it. You can vote this bug so they will solve it faster: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176

Comment: Hey Dom (and everyone) kind of a nit-picky question, but I used the accept attribute (for csv, xls, and xlsx files) and it works great, except it also allows the user--at least on my machine--to select icon files as well, and then flashes an error message that says "FILE NAME: Catastrophic failure". It will simply allow you to choose another file after that, so not THAT catastrophic, just wondered if anyone had an idea why this would happen?

Comment: @DavidRouten the accept attribute would just filter file types. You would have to use file validation as well to prevent users from selecting other file types. Hope that helps!

Comment: Note: in Chrome (v 32) it works even with combined types like txt and csv: <input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept="text/plain, .csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />

Comment: I wonder why such an obvious file selector feature is not supported by all modern browsers...maybe issues with native OS support, a best effort strategy is the way to go.

Comment: @HowardShieh what version of safari are you using?

Comment: @Dom 7.0.3(9537.75.14)

Comment: for csv file in FF on ubuntu accept="text/csv" works not ".csv"

Comment: <input type="file" accept=".csv" /> is not works in Firefox. Is there any other solution to make as works this in Firefox.

Comment: Is there a way to combine two value of Mime type?

Comment: <input type="file" accept=".csv" /> doesn't work here either.

Comment: `<input type="file" accept=".csv, text/csv" />` worked for me in firefox, chrome and opera on mac. only .csv did not work in all browsers.

Comment: when we are using accept=".csv", why there is a semi-colon ( *.csv; ) at last of filter tab in file upload dialouge box. ( Ubuntu 14.04- Firefox 40.0.3 )

Comment: i used accept="<*.csv>" it working fine and in filter tab it doesn't contained "*.csv;", it contained " CSV Document". Thnx

Comment: yuup,, it works for me. thanks a lot. To select ONLY *.xls and *.xlsx using this code : `accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"`

Comment: For the xls and xlsx mime types mentioned above, make sure that you have the correct player application installed (like Microsoft excel or word etc).

Comment: @ni8mr try accept=".xml" or accept="application/xml" or accept="text/xml"

Comment: excel type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Comment: in MVC 5, in a .cshtml View, '@accept = ".xlsx, .xls, .csv" ' works perfectly. The solution above with 'accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ' does not work.

Comment: After my test, on 【macOS 10.15.7 Catalina】, the answer of 【Dom / Rikin Patel】 cannot recognize the [.xlsx] file normally. So I sum up the following answers : 【accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx, text/csv, application/csv,
text/comma-separated-values, application/csv, application/excel,
application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext, application/vnd. ms-excel,
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"】

Comment: As I was expecting to have to hunt down a mime-type, I was happily surprised by the simplicity of just '.whatever' to work. And since some comments on this page were suggesting lack of support by 'modern browsers', I'm happy to report that on windows it works just fine in at least Chrome, Firefox and Edge (august 2023).

Answer (score 265):

These days you can just use the file extension

```
<input type="file" ID="fileSelect" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"/>
```

Comment: Although amazingly this (and the alternative `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel`) still doesn't appear to work on Edge 41.16299.820.0 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875617/input-accept-attribute-in-microsoft-edge#32214646 https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/13661175-full-spec-support-for-accept-in-input-type-file

Answer (score 42):

Dom this attribute is very old and not accepted in modern browsers as far as I know, But here is an alternative to it, Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkfile(sender) {
    var validExts = new Array(".xlsx", ".xls", ".csv");
    var fileExt = sender.value;
    fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
    if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
      alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
               validExts.toString() + " types.");
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
</script>

<input type="file" id="file" onchange="checkfile(this);" />
```

I guess it'll help you of course you can change this script according to your needs.

Comment: Cool workaround but I do not understand why such an attribute is considered 'old'. This is a basic file selector feature on nearly every OS, the browsers should do their best to make it work and it would help many users...

Comment: The accept attribute is not old and is supported in the major browsers except for IE/Edge: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept. Please rephrase your answer as it is misguiding.

Comment: The most important aspect of the `accept` attribute is the hint it provides to the open-file dialog.  The user should be presented with matching files by default, presumably with an option to select other types if they wish -- this is how most modern browsers behave now.

Comment: sender.value no longer works. It should be sender.target.value

Answer (score 17):

I have used `text/comma-separated-values` for CSV mime-type in accept attribute and it works fine in Opera. Tried `text/csv` without luck.

Some others MIME-Types for CSV if the suggested do not work:

- text/comma-separated-values
- text/csv
- application/csv
- application/excel
- application/vnd.ms-excel
- application/vnd.msexcel
- text/anytext

Source: http://filext.com/file-extension/CSV

Comment: Hi Dom! I want to say sorry because your answer (marked as right) is OK and I do not have many attention on it before because I was testing the site in Opera only. After testing in other browsers, I see that you answer is more complete. But it does not work in all browsers. Firefox 17 does not support accept attr how a filter in File Dialog (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83749#c14), so this property is suspenseful for me. I will use javascript file validation anyway, but use text/csv in accept attr because it is the default of IANA http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types

Answer (score 16):

This didn't work for me under Safari 10:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

I had to write this instead:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/csv" />
```

Comment: Hii,,, it working well on my safari too. But how if we want to accept excel documents? do you have any clue ? @trojan

Comment: Check the answer of Big Money. TLDR; 
<input type="file" ID="fileSelect" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"/>

Answer (score 8):

just write the extensions you want to accept comma separated in the action atr in the out

```
<input type="file" accept=".any, .ext, .you, .want">
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the top-answer, CSV files, for example, are reported as text/plain under macOS but as application/vnd.ms-excel under Windows.
So I use this:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/plain, .csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can know the correct content-type for any file by just doing the following:

1) Select interested file,

2) And run in console this:

```
console.log($('.file-input')[0].files[0].type);
```

You can also set attribute "multiple" for your input to check content-type for several files at a time and do next:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.file-input')[0].files.length; i++){
    console.log($('.file-input')[0].files[i].type);
}
```

Attribute accept has some problems with multiple attribute and doesn't work correctly in this case.

Comment: Doing this and selecting a .csv file I get `type: "text/csv"` but using `accept="text/csv"` on an input doesn't filter files correctly (tested on Brave / Chromium). Using `accept=".csv"` works though.

For playing it safe if you don't want to test in all common browsers I'd use both mime type and file extension like so `accept="text/csv,.csv"`.

Answer (score 5):

After my test, on 【macOS 10.15.7 Catalina】, the answer of 【Dom / Rikin Patel】 cannot recognize the [.xlsx] file normally.

I personally summarized the practice of most of the existing answers and passed personal tests. Sum up the following answers:

> ```
> accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx, text/csv, application/csv,
> text/comma-separated-values, application/csv, application/excel,
> application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext, application/vnd. ms-excel,
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I have modified the solution of @yogi. The addition is that when the file is of incorrect format I reset the input element value.

```js
function checkFile(sender, validExts) {
  var fileExt = sender.value;
  fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
  if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0 && fileExt != "") {
    alert("Invalid file selected, valid files are of " +
             validExts.toString() + " types.");
    $(sender).val("");
    return false;
  }
  else return true;
}
```

I have custom verification buildin, because in open file window the user can still choose the options `"All files ('*')"`, regardless if I explicitly set the accept attribute in input element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following accept types

```html
<input id="upload_file" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,.doc, .docx,.xls,.xlsx,.pdf,.csv," name="upload_file" type="file"/>
```

Comment: This is my kind of answer. Simple and straight to the point with a working example. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Now you can use new html5 input validation attribute `pattern=".+\.(xlsx|xls|csv)"`.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern), `This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored.` Regarding the file input, they go on to say `file: A control that lets the user select a file. Use the accept attribute to define the types of files that the control can select.`