# How to select only multiple .csv files in html5 input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am using the html5 input tag to multiselect only .csv files. I have so far

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept=".csv" multiple />
```

but when I click browse, it shows all file types. How can I get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

Or take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv#answer-11834872).

Comment: This one had 4 options in the dropdown, 3 Microsoft xls stuff, and the `all files` which is default.

Comment: Have you take a look to the link?

Comment: The suggestions in the link don't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html), `accept` is used to specify mime types, not file extensions. Try `accept="text/csv"` instead.