# javascript file type not caught?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am using the javascript file api to read a file and I want to get its type out. I am mainly using it to upload audio and video files. However when i upload amr, 3gp, and aac audio files, javascript can't figure out the filetype. I need to know the filetypes for the different audio formats as I use the files differently depending on the format. Is there anyway for me to figure out the format for the above mentioned files? I have supplied the code I use below.

```
var f = this.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = function (ev2) {
            console.dir(ev2);
            //$('#image').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
            //extra[extra.length] = ev2.target.result;

            extra[extra.length] = ev2.target.result;

            var splitted = ev2.target.result.split(','); //get the type
            fileType[fileType.length] = splitted[0];
            console.log("splitted[0]: "+splitted[0]);
            console.log("f.type: "+f.type);

        };

        fr.readAsDataURL(f);
```

regards

Comment: Why not split the filename on "." and get the last field (the exstension)?

Comment: I would do that, but the powers that be have asked me not to saying that its unreliable, as its easy to change the extension for a given file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
[Source](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)
[Demo](http://codepen.io/matt-west/full/KjEHg)
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nmzt/)

```
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var textType = /text.*/;
if (file.type.match(textType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    //onload code
  }

  reader.readAsText(file);  
} else {
  alert( "File not supported!");
}
```

or also this code:

```
    var file = $("#inputFile")[0].files;        
    alert(file[0].type);
```

Comment: I cannot un-support the file, all audio files must be read(supported) and their type( amr, acc, etc) taken out, so that depending on different audio types i can do different functions, in the case of this code even if i change the texttype to 'audio.*', the above mentioned audio types become unsupported

Comment: In the second case the type gets printed as an empty ''

Comment: @SajithDilshanJamal with which type of file did you try?

Comment: audio files with the formats: amr, acc, and 3gp, try 'amr' type first if you are planning to test,as thats what I am trying to get working the most

Comment: @SajithDilshanJamal try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv