# what are the allowed mime types in file accept attribute?

Tags: html, file-upload

what are the allowed mime types in file accept attribute?

```
<input type="file" name="fileupload" accept="application/csv,application/pdf"/>
```

I tried images, video, audio these all worked but csv, pdf, doc not working are these allowed in this accept attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Described on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) the accept attribute can handle the following values:

`<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type" />`

- **file_extension**

  - A file extension starting with the U+002E FULL STOP character, e.g: .gif, .jpg, .png, .doc
- **audio/***

  - All sound files are accepted
- **video/***

  - All video files are accepted
- **image/***

  - All image files are accepted
- **media_type**

  - A valid media type, with no parameters (A list of valid media_types is provided [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)).

There are all of your asked types described (e.g. `.csv`)

(Possible related to [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful))

Comment: <input type="file" name="attachment" accept="text/csv" />
this is not working.

Comment: what browser do you use for testing? have you tried `.csv` instead?

Comment: sure the right version? With the media_type i also had problems like mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv) but with the file_extension it works like a charm ...