# How can I validate for only CSV file uploads using the pattern attribute using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="txtFile" pattern="?" id="txtFile" class="required"/>
</form>

pattern = '?'
```

Using which regular expression I would add the validation for the ONLY CSV FILE ALLOW.

If I upload .xls or any another file then it will display an error.

Comment: you need javascript/jquery code to validate

Comment: @Disha : yes , it should be possible using js , but i have to create using html5..

Comment: @Disha: ahan nice editing

Comment: @Disha: I suspect that this isolated closing tag is more often used than any other (obviously in non-HTML text, or should be). I can’t prove it — Google, Yahoo search, and Bing all ignore the non-alphabetics when told to search for — but that’s how ISTM.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Now you can use the new HTML5 input validation attribute:

```
pattern="^.+\.(xlsx|xls|csv)$"
```

Accept type for other files (Reference: HTML5 Documentation):

**For CSV:**

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

**For Excel files, 2003-2007 (.xls):**

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

**For Excel files, 2010 (.xlsx):**

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

**For text files (.txt):**

```
<input type="file" accept="text/plain" />
```

**For image files (.png, .jpg, etc.):**

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

**For HTML files (.htm, .html):**

```
<input type="file" accept="text/html" />
```

**For video files (.avi, .mpg, .mpeg, .mp4):**

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" />
```

**For audio files (.mp3, .wav, etc.):**

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*" />
```

**For PDF files, use:**

```
<input type="file" accept=".pdf" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv#11834872 ???

Comment: @Disha: of course, reference mentioned. you can get online aswell

Answer (score 8):

It is not easy to accept just one of the file types. It depends on different OS and installed text reading programmes. In Unix type systems if you pass `.csv` file you will get `.csv` file type, but if you will pass the same file on Windows you will ger different file types, such as `text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.msexcel, text/anytext`.

It calls `mime-types` and can be different for any of text type files.
Here is the link where you can [read more](https://filext.com/file-extension/CSV).

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
<input type="file" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" class="required" accept=".csv,text/csv" />
```

Mentioning the `MIME` type is good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" name="txtFile" accept=".csv" id="txtFile" class="required" />
```

Comment: Using the accept attribute you can validate any kind of file extension e.g. accept=".csv,.xls,.xlsx"