# How to make input type= file Should accept only .xlsx and filename contain substring

Tags: html

[image]

I want to upload a .xlsx file to my systems with condition that the file name contains a specified string.

For example: I want to upload file whose name contains "Paper", so the file browser should not display files which don't contain "Paper" in their name.

For the example in the photo that I attached in this post, the file 'Order#...' should not be displayed.

How can i do it? Is it possible to implement this idea?
thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [accept attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp)
Try this code

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv)

Comment: That does not provide the full solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use accept attribute with input type file

```html
<input type="file" name="my-file" id="" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accept attribute. Some older browser do not support it, but i think it is not an issue yet