# Uploading CSV file in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I'm having issues uploading a CSV file in codeigniter.

I am getting the error:

```
array(1) { ["error"] => string(64) "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." }
```

Ok!!

but I am setting allowed_types like this:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

and i have this in mimes.php:

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'),
```

So any ideas why I am still getting this error?

$_FILES dump:

```
Array
(
    [name] => default questions.csv
    [type] => application/force-download
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbkXxUd
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 5899
)
```

Comment: Type `application/force-download` is a problem , file's is currpt , it does not have a valid format and mime type , to be declared csv file. fi you put `application/force-download` inside mime list for csv, then it will allow the file to be uploaded . but still `application/force-download` is being added from invalid header `content-disposition` , which should be a `content-disposition:attachment`

Comment: add `echo $this->upload->display_errors();` and post the complete Error

Comment: @Spartan That's the error I've posted to the top of the question?

Comment: `echo pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` add file name with `$_file` and post the output

Comment: it throws an error on this `pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` says $filename is wrong

Comment: replace` $filename` with `$_FILE['html_name_of the file']`

Comment: What file? controller/model/view/csv file?

Comment: there is an html part to upload file from view. AN dthere is name of that too. Add the name to this. Some thing like this `<input type="file" name="pic">`. So $_FILE should be `$_FILE['pic']`

Comment: Ok yes already posted the value of $_FILE above

Comment: add like this `pathinfo($_FILE['add_your_file_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: nope, doesnt like that, throws an error: Message: Undefined variable: _FILE

Comment: No no, do this.: `pathinfo($_FILES['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Also, does your form element have this attribute? `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - something like this? `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: This is an interesting question/answer as well, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$config['allowed_types'] = '*';

This should work
.Also check your upload.php or mimes.php. Use the latest one.