# Django - show result (error) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, forms

I have form, that accepts number between 1-6 and a file. You can see code in my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611769/django-javascript-modal-form-validation

I have to validate form, without having to reload it as it is modal form and it closes on refresh (or is should open it on refresh, but i don't really like the idea of reloading). So i want the modal to show error, if there is any (wrong file type, model already exists...) How would i achieve this?

Somebody suggested me to post form asynchronously and show error with javascript. How would i send javascript message from views in django, without the page having to reload? Could it be done with Json? How?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to options:

1. Django validation view which will return [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)
   In that case you send your data to this view which will check if data are valid and return appropriate response. Then you parse response and show error if any.
2. Javascript validation. You make validator in your javascript code which will check if filetype is suitable etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11834872/6555866) you have example how to allow only specified types of files.

In **both** cases you should validate your data in view in which you are saving to Database/server while someone could send data directly to your saving view(e.g. with Postman).
I would suggest second approach because it is faster and one less call to server.

Comment: thank you for answer. I think i have to go with Json, as I have to check in views if model already exists, which cannot be done with javascript. Do you have any example, how to handle json with javascript in template?

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: I use whatever i have to,

Comment: any recommendations?

Comment: Check this link at the bottom of the page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/
or this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
You just make ajax request and then in .done function you can check whether it passed validation.

Comment: But can i post multiple pictures using ajax?

Comment: I am not shure, but I think there is one package for file upload with jQuery which can handle more then one picture. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Is getting json response from view not possible withou using ajax?

Comment: It is the most common way to make requests and handle responses. If you would use Angular you could use their http module to do requests.