# How to accept add just media files (video and photo) and No All Files section

Tags: javascript, html, upload, jquery-file-upload

I have this at html page

```
<input type="file" id="ajax-upload-id-1508413400253" name="Media" accept="video/*,image/*" 
style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 
100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0;">
```

And at .js

```
 manageMedia_Uploader = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
            url: "/Ajax/JsonProvider?Method=SaveMedia",
            fileName: "Media",
            autoSubmit: false,
            multiple: false,
            acceptFiles: "video/*,image/*",
            dynamicFormData: function () {
                return { MediaFriendlyName: $("#ManageMedia-MediaFriendlyName").val(), MediaID: mediaID }
            },


SaveMedia: function (mediaID) {

        if (mediaID == 0) {
            manageMedia_Uploader.startUpload();
        } else {
             //util
        }
    },
```

My problem is I want to just add picture and video nothing else. Thanks for this code give me 2 option while selecting files. Custom files and All files.

```
acceptFiles: "video/*,image/*",
```

How can i prevent All Files section ? Just Custom Files will appear ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to add input type="file" attribute, to accept media files, you can do it like this :
HTML

```
<input type="file" id="ajax-upload-id-1508413400253" name="Media" accept="audio/*,video/*,image/*" 
style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 
100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0;">
```

JS

```
manageMedia_Uploader = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
            url: "/Ajax/JsonProvider?Method=SaveMedia",
            fileName: "Media",
            autoSubmit: false,
            multiple: false,
            acceptFiles: "image/*, video/*",
            dynamicFormData: function () {
                return { MediaFriendlyName: $("#ManageMedia-MediaFriendlyName").val(), MediaID: mediaID }
            },


SaveMedia: function (mediaID) {

        if (mediaID == 0) {
            manageMedia_Uploader.startUpload();
        } else {
             //util
        }
    },
```

More :

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

[HTML Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv)

Comment: I can still add txt or something if I change custom files to  all files when open file select window