# how to read and validate the excel file in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Current i am able to read the excel but not able to validate and if user select other file instead of excel file then need to get a popup that "Please select excel file only"

Component.html

```
<input type="file" accept=".xlsx" class="btn btn-success" (change)="onFileChange($event)">

<button type="file" class="btn dark btn-outline" 
  (click)="uploadfile()">Upload</button>
```

Component.ts

```
 data=[];
 onFileChange(evt: any) {
    debugger
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length == 1 && evt.target.accept === ".xlsx" ){
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      console.log(wb);
      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      /* save data */
      this.data = <any>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header: 1}));
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);

   }
  }
------
uploadfile() {
    let keys = this.data.shift();
    let resArr = this.data.map((e) => {
        let obj = {};
        keys.forEach((key, i) => {
            obj[key] = e[i];
        });
        return obj;
    });
    console.log(resArr);
    const _data = {
        data: resArr
    }
    this.cinemaService.newoperater(_data).subscribe();
  }
```

`onFileChange()` this method will read the data & `uploadfile()` this method will convert array of array into object and send it to API

please help me with the validation of excel file

Comment: "not able to" is not an error message or problem statement. What precisely is happening (or not happening) in your code?

Answer (score 4):

you can set the HTML Element directly to accept only csv:

```html
<input type="file" ID="fileSelect" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"/>
```

[HTML Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv)

**EDIT:**

Some Browsers (i.e. Safari 10) may have problems using `<input type="file" accept=".csv" />`. In this case use

```
<input type="file" accept="text/csv" />
```

greetings

Comment: The OP is already using the accept attribute and has not specified .csv as a requirement.

Comment: this will not provide me the validation popup.

Answer (score 0):

List item

```js
 var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) => {

         let csvData = reader.result;
         let csvRecordsArray = (<any>csvData).trim().split(/\r\n|\n/);
         let header = csvRecordsArray[0].split(",");
       
        // for (var j = 0; j <= header.length; j++) {
            //if (header[j] == "") {
               //this.helper.showAlertMessage("Missing Header in CSV file.", "error");
               //this.myvariable.nativeElement.value = '';
               let headerdata = header.length;
               console.log(headerdata)
               for (var i = 1; i <= csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
                  var data = csvRecordsArray[i].split(",");
                  var dataCount = data.length;
                  if (headerdata !== dataCount) {

                     this.helper.showAlertMessage("Missing column or Invalid  in CSV file.", "error");
                     this.myvariable.nativeElement.value = '';
                     

                  }

               }
            //}
        // }
         
      }
      reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

      const resp = await this.fileObjectService.uploadFile(this.fileObject.databaseId, file, this.fileObject.tableName, 10);
```

`

Comment: It validate dot csv file if any column or header and data mismatch it shows the error message