# How to Select pdf file from server to upload in other folder

Tags: php

How to Select pdf file from server to upload in other folder.

```
<form method="post" action="pdf2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="PDF2Image" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="file"..

Comment: Do you have any code that you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload file from server. So need to do Copy one folder to other folder. Thank you.

copy(file,to_file)