# Dropzone show only CSV & XLS files in dialog box

Tags: excel, csv, dropzone.js, xls

I used dropzone as CSV/XLS file uploader. I use this option to filter and restrict CSV/XLS file:

```
acceptedFiles: "text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
```

Now I just see XLS file in windows dialog box and doesn't see CSV file. Off course when I change filter drop-down to all files, I see CSV file and select it. But I wanna to method or option to solve this issue.

Do you have any solution for see both XLS/CSV files together?

Comment: Did you try using the file extensions instead of mime types? .csv and .xls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropzone.js simply puts the values from the AcceptedFiles attribute directly into the  html component.

```
<input accept="text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
```

It looks like text/csv is not an accepted value even though it is a valid mime type. **.csv** is recommended.

See here [HTML Input="file" Accept Attribute File Type (CSV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv).