# How to configure paparse to detect only CSV files

Tags: reactjs, papaparse

How to configure paparse to detect only CSV files when trying to upload a file from local.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv

Comment: Do you know how i can use the same for react-papaparse library in react