# Vuetify file input accept text/csv not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, mime-types

I have a Vuetify fie input:

```html
<v-file-input
  accept="text/csv"
  label="File input"
  placeholder="Select your CSV files"
></v-file-input>
```

I want to upload only CSV files, but the **accept="text/csv"** not working, I can upload any file,

> I have test other type like **accept="image/*"** and its work.

---

https://codepen.io/AiAbdrahim/pen/oNLyYvm

---

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.16/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.16/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input
      accept="text/csv"
      label="File input"
      placeholder="Select your CSV files"
    ></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this something like this, it works on vue.

```
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" ref="inputFile" @input="myUploadFile()" hidden />
```

And write a setUploadFile method

```
myUploadFile(){
 this.file = this.$refs.inputFile.files[0];
 if (this.file.type == "text/csv"){
    // Api call
 }
 else {
   this.showAlert("error", "The file-type doesn't belong to text/csv")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to Vuetify. You have inserted a wrong accept value.
[html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv)

Answer (score 0):

You need also to include a rule preventing that:

```
<v-file-input
  accept="text/csv"
  :rules="(value) => !value || value.type == 'text/csv' || 'Only CSV files allowed'"
  label="File input"
  placeholder="Select your CSV files"
></v-file-input>
```

Comment: Rules must be an array, make it like, :rules="[(value) => !value || value.type == 'text/csv' || 'Only CSV files allowed]'"