# Accept attribute is not working in File input

Tags: angular, file, input

I am trying to have a file input which accepts only excel file.

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="p-24 pb-0 m-0" fusePerfectScrollbar>
            <div fxLayout="row" style="margin-top: 1rem;">
                <input type="file" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
            </div>
</div>
```

in TS file-

```
uploadFile(event): void {
        const fileForm = event.target.files[0];
        this.formDataForm.append('file', fileForm);
    }
```

I want to restrict the user from uploading any type of other file, but any file type is uploaded now.
**accept** attribute is not working here.

Comment: Tip: Do not use this attribute as a validation tool. File uploads should be validated on the server. from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,be%20validated%20on%20the%20server.

Comment: @SiddharthSeth got it, but I want to add a file type validation in client side also.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832930/html-input-file-accept-attribute-file-type-csv